# Native Facebook Audience Network ad not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I implemented native ad with facebook audience network, but when you tap on call to action button or on the ad nothing happens.

I call method `[nativeAd registerViewForInteraction:self.nativeAdView withViewController:nil];` but it does nothing.

Code that I'm using to create ad:

```
 nativeAdView.uxTitle.text = titleForAd;
nativeAdView.uxDescription.text = bodyTextForAd;
[coverImage loadImageAsyncWithBlock:^(UIImage * _Nullable image) {
    nativeAdView.uxImageView.image = image;
}];
//nativeAdView.uxImageView.image = coverImage;
[nativeAdView.uxCTAButton setTitle:titleForAdButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];

FBAdChoicesView *adChoicesView = [[FBAdChoicesView alloc] initWithNativeAd:nativeAd];
[nativeAdView addSubview:adChoicesView];
[adChoicesView updateFrameFromSuperview];


[self.uxScrollView addSubview:nativeAdView];

y += nativeAdView.frame.size.height + 30;
[self.uxScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.uxScrollView.frame.size.width, y)];


// Register the native ad view and its view controller with the
// native ad instance
[nativeAd registerViewForInteraction:self.nativeAdView withViewController:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved, nativeAd instance needs to be saved.

Comment: i am facing clickable issue in swift, could you please help me out.